# Cómo extraer las filas de un DataFrame seguidas de un patrón?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estoy intentando extraer las filas o registros de un dataframe que tiene headers en él(Atlantic Division, Metropolitan Division, Central Division, Atlantic Division), los cuales se repiten a lo largo del Dataframe con distintos registros después de ellos, es decir, se repiten las divisiones, más no, los equipos. Lo que trato hacer, es extraer los equipos que están dentro de una division en particular.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías hacer es crear una lista con todas las divisiones.

```
divisions = ['Atlantic Division', 'Metropolitan Division', 'Central Division']
```

Si son muchas divisiones y no las podes sacar manualmente sería fácil de extraer de la columna **GP** por ejemplo, ya que los equipos tienen números y las divisiones su nombre.
Luego podes crear una nueva columna donde va a especificar la división

```
df['division'] = ''
```

y recorrería el **df**, si la columna **team** tiene el nombre de la división la guardo en una variable y sino, le asigno la variable al equipo en la nueva columna.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['team'] in divisions:
        division = row['team']
    else:
        df.loc[index, ['division']] = division
```

Te quedaría algo así
[image: dataframe ejemplo]

Después sólo te queda eliminar las filas de las divisiones y seleccionar los equipos según la nueva columna.

Si el dataframe es muy grande te recomiendo que mires [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas) donde explican las mejores formas de iterar un df